# Simple Question on OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

Say we have a serial application that stops normally for a while 'till a completely independent function is computed. How can one use OpenMP to spawn that function only to a thread and only printf its result when it ends? [without stopping the main application]

EDIT: Can it be done if the independent function is run inside the main app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute functions in parallel using openmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431821/execute-functions-in-parallel-using-openmp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **parallel sections**.

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
   #pragma omp section
   YourMainApp ();

   #pragma omp section
   YourIndepFunction ();
}
```

Comment: TY. Can the above be done by having the independent function inside the main app?

Comment: They both should run in independent threads. But I guess ultimately it's actually up to the OpenMP implementation...

Comment: [I edited the initial comment-question] Can the above be done by having the independent function inside the main app?

Comment: Nevermind, I opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292191/can-a-function-run-independently-inside-a-main-app-openmp and it answered my confusion.